# SQL Server : reconnect after lost connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I want open WPF program, then SQL Server database is off and when database is back online, WPF should auto connect to the database. If I restart SQL Server, keep alive program and try connect    to database until connection is available. Should I catch the exception and then repeat something?

I try restart application then I got exception, but anyway my program crash and stop working.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //how stop crash? //
        //System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();
        return ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use a recursive method to check if connection can be established. But if its the best solution for performance I doubt

Answer (score 0):

The thing to do is to centralize the creation of connections in a single static method for your entire application.

```
public static SqlConnection getConnection()
{
      string conn = string.Empty;
      conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["quality"].ConnectionString;
      SqlConnection aConnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
      return aConnection;
}
```

In your code,every time you use a connection try this :

```
public int test()
{
    SqlConnection conn = null;

    try
    {
        try
        {
            conn = StaticContext.getConnection();
            conn.Open();
            //TODO OPERATION



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //return ex.ToString();
            return -1;//MY_ERROR_CODE;
        }
    }


    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return 1//MY_SUCCES_CODE;

}
```

When you call DB method manage so the error:

```
if (test() == -1)
{
   //MESSAGE BOX ERROR OR OTHER
}
```